# Convert Mac font to Windows format?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, conversion, fonts

I have a font that was used on Mac OS X 10.5. Mac recognizes it as a font file. Windows Vista shows it as a "File".

Changing the file extension doesn't work. I tried both .otf and .ttf and neither worked. (Surprise! I didn't thinks so, but I'd be a fool for asking if that was the answer, so I tried...) Perhaps I need to try a different extension?

Are there any utilities to convert the font? A Windows equivalent? It's called Franco. (FrancoNormal, actually.)

Thanks.

EDIT:

DFontSplitter didn't work. I saw something online about "data fork" and "resource fork" that has to match up. Can someone please explain that?

Do I need both for a font conversion? What do I tell my graphic designer to send me?

EDIT 2:

The font doesn't work when downloaded to Mac OS X either. (A different machine from the original.) "Get Info" reveals that there is no file extension, leading me to believe that this is the newer font format. Where wold I find the the "data fork" and "resource fork" on the Mac? I want to be able to tell the designer exactly where to look.

EDIT 3:

DFontSplitter works on the original computer but not on my PC. I converted and emailed myself the fonts from the graphic designers laptop. I guess it has to do with the data being  stored in a "fork" whatnot.

Thanks, Matt for that article.

Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple article will give your an overview or OS X font formats as well as answer your "data fork" question.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22195

What is the extension of your font on its native system?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am still not clear on what a "data fork" is. See my edits above for answer an to your question, please. +1.

Comment: What font are you dealing with? Just in case we can solve this issue by just getting a new copy.

Comment: The font is not available online. I checked. (It is, for $9.90...) Problem solved though by using DFontSplitter on the original machine.

Comment: You get the check for helping and the article gave me useful info.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, if anybody ever reads this.

I just downloaded TransType 4 **Trial Version for Windows** and it fixed badly extracted/converted fonts that were extracted from a .dfont container using DFontSplitter on a Mac machine. I don't know how long the trial version is "open", but it seems to offer the full functionality for at least 30 minutes :D.

Most probably, you can also just open a .dfont container with it and extract everything in it to make it usable on a Windows or Linux machine.